# How is it called when you use "mail" in "mail.google.com" for example?

Tags: url

I know it is probably a dumb question, but I don't know how to refer to it.

How is it called when we use the subdirectory comming first in the URL and how is it configured? Is it something configured on the server?

Comment: That isn't a subdirectory; it's a domain name just like any other domain name.

Comment: This is called a "[subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)" (although, technically `google` is also a subdomain of `com`).

Comment: More info here: http://serverfault.com/questions/222095/what-is-the-canonical-name-for-domain-names-with-extra-parts

Comment: Are you asking how `http://www.google.com/mail/` becomes `http://mail.google.com/mail/`? It is called a redirect. The server listening for requests on `www.google.com` reads the requests and when the requested context is `/mail/`, it returns a `301 Moved` with the URL of `http://mail.google.com/mail/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called *subdomain* and it's configured as a DNS entry and Web server listens requests to the whole subdomain.

Some domain registrars have DNS host record configuration, where you set up - for example - `mail.youdomain.com` for a given IP address. Finally, domain registrar's DNS server points to the configured IP address, and Web server receives a request with that IP address and the `mail.youdomain.com` host name to identify which Web site should be served to the client (f.e. a Web browser).

Configuration may depend on the Web server technology (i.e. Apache, IIS, ...).

Comment: I agree that the configuration approach is different, but the web server term that ties this all in together is bindings: http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx  Bindings work with DNS to create a route to the website over the network, but are based on separate technologies.

Comment: @RandomUs1r Well, I believe OP wasn't expecting a Web Server university master class :D BTW, if you feel you can add more detailed info to this question, you should add another answer.

Comment: I think of it from a web dev standpoint and just wanted to add the concept that ties urls & web servers together, since OP was asking about configuration.  Your answer does directly answer the question though (up until the last line), thus I didn't post another one.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I'll try to add your suggestion during today